# javax.websocket.Session api

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, websocket, java-ee-7

i need to retrieve a session id but Eclipse tell me 
"The method getId() is undefined for the type Session"

here the header :

```
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
```

here the error :

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session){
    System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection"); 
    //session.getId() is undefined.
    try {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection Established");
        //same here getBasicRemote is undefined
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I build my project with gradle. I think i included all the depencies.

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
compile 'org.glassfish.main.extras:glassfish-embedded-all:4.0-b72'
compile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

then i run gradle eclipse. But getId() still undefined.

If someone have an idea ! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the 'org.glassfish.main.extras:glassfish-embedded-all:4.0-b72' lib that override the javax websocket api.

Worked using org.glassfish.main.extras:glassfish-embedded-all:4.1 instead.
Weird.